# Application Insights Operation.Id from an HTTP header

Tags: asp.net, .net, logging, azure-application-insights, diagnostics

My project uses `ApplicationInsightsHttpModule` which initializes `Operation.Id` from `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.RequestTelemetry` HTTP value set by a client UI application. Now I want my API to be consumed by a third party which will provide `X-Operation-Id` HTTP header to correlate our activities. How do I make Application Insights to initialize `Operation.Id` from that header if it's present in a request?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171747/adding-correlation-id-to-automatically-generated-telemetry-with-app-insights) says that the standard context is managed automatically by AI so I need a code sample that shows how to properly initialize `Operation.Id` with a custom value. The following code isn't working, the header value is ignored:

```
var operationInitializer = TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.OfType<Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer>().FirstOrDefault();

if (operationInitializer != null)
{
      operationInitializer.RootOperationIdHeaderName = "X-Operation-Id";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding correlation id to automatically generated telemetry with App Insights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171747/adding-correlation-id-to-automatically-generated-telemetry-with-app-insights)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the question was asked AI SDK had version 2.2. Recently I've upgraded to the latest version 2.4 and it's working now as intended. So, if you pass say 'HELLO' in `X-Operation-Id` HTTP header (you still need that code in the question in `Application_Start()`) and then ask for a telemetry in `Application_BeginRequest()` (or wherever `HttpContext` is available):

```
    RequestTelemetry telemetry = HttpContext.Current.GetRequestTelemetry();
```

`telemetry.Id` will contain something like `|HELLO.d0b9d5b7_`.
That hexadecimal suffix increases if you pass 'HELLO' in the next request so `Id` is always unique. I don't know if that can be overridden though.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you included in your question should be working at first glance: you are looking for correct initializer and overriding correct property. However there could be multiple reasons why it is not working as expected, and debugging this is hard, because it would require you to actually step into Application Insights code (if you do decide, [the sources for every release are archived on GH](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/releases)).

My recommendation in your case would be to take a different approach - instead of trying to override this property, create and register your own telemetry initializer to set Operation.ID from your header. If you set this property, OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer will ignore it and not override. This way you confirm that your headers can be read correctly, and you can easily set breakpoint in Initialize method to debug.

Comment: My biggest concerns are that I'm not sure how to *properly* initialize it and  access `HttpContext` within the initializer. Is it just `HttpContext.Current`? Will this wotk with OWIN based apps?